# Why no @types for Semantic-ui-react? Will @types/semantic-ui work? Can I get by without @types?

Tags: typescript, types, semantic-ui-react

I'm using typescript on my node.js react-app.

Would like to use semantic-ui-react. 
However I cannot seem to find a @types/semantic-ui-react. I can only find @types/semantic-ui.

Will @types/semantic-ui suffice? Can I get by without a @types?

I noticed in past comments they were working on @types for react back in 2016, but cannot seem to find a @types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typings are included to Semantic UI React by default, you don't need to install any additional packages.

https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-React/blob/v0.86.0/package.json#L8